# Why is Jquery scroll not binding?

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I'm trying to create a certain parallax effect and I found a great example.

I also need a resizing header, so I need Jquery scroll to work. This is working in the rest of the site, but for some reason not on this page. I added a fiddle.

[Fiddle](http://bit.ly/1wLC7eO)

Comment: Please don't use url shorteners, especially to "sidestep" important quality filters.

Comment: How pathetic. Please, do something useful with your time. The "desired behaviour" is clearly written. In the fiddle you can reproduce the error (really, maybe you should actually try it before giving someone a penalty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrollbar doesn't belong to the window, but to the `.parallax` element

```
$('.parallax').scroll(function () { ...
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fo07yehd/1/)

The scroll event doesn't bubble !